# Rascal outputs "Got NPE for node ..." to console when calling "createAstsFromDirectory"

Tags: shell, rascal

I have the following code snippet:

```
println("bll1");
createAstsFromDirectory(location, false);
println("bll2");
```

When I run this for any valid `location` that denotes a Java project, I get the following output (varying per project):

```
bll1
Got NPE for node String[] args
Got NPE for node String[] args
Got NPE for node blah=6
Got NPE for node String[] args
Got NPE for node String[] args
bll2
```

This is an issue, as I'm using an external program to read the shell output. Also, for big projects this spams the console a lot (the above output is for a project with two small (<30sloc) classes). Smallsql yields at least 1000 of these `Got NPE for node ...` lines.

Furthermore:

- This happens in both the stable AND unstable shell of Rascal
- This doesn't happen in the console for the Eclipse plugin
- This doesn't happen when using the `createAstFromM3` and `createAstFromFile` functions on the same files/projects.

Comment: in the Eclipse console context the classpath is automagically constructed from the project context that is analyzed and from the JRE configuration that Eclipse is currently using, that's why you don't see the same bug there.

Comment: it can be pretty daunting to construct a full jar classpath from scratch. there is a project to help construct a jar classpath from a maven project here: https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal-java-build-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that types can not be resolved properly on your commandline by the Eclipse Java compiler. This triggers an internal bug which triggers a null pointer exception which should actually never happen. The ASTs produced are still valid, but the resolved types are going to be missing completely.

In this case the type resolver already fails on `java.lang.String[]`, so the java run-time library is not even on the compiler's classpath.

This should fix it: include the JRE jar into the `classPath` keyword parameter:

```
createAstFromFile(..., classPath=[|file:///path/to/your/rt.jar|, ...possibly some other jars...])
```

Comment: I do have it on `false` in the code snippet I sent in my question right?

Comment: right! I missed that. I checked the code and the parameter is pushed correctly through the different functions. So that means that the JRE is needed on the classpath to avoid the NPE even if bindings are not resolved.

Comment: But that does not explain why `createAstFromFile`, where it doesn't matter whether `collectBindings` is `true` or `false`, doesn't yield any problems. Thanks for helping me out btw.

Comment: Mmm. You're right. I'll have to dig deeper later this week. . Does the bigger classpath solve your issue?

Comment: Having to provide a full path to my `rt.jar` would not be a very viable solution, as I want my program to work on any system. I'll go with `createAstFromFile` for now and use an external program to scan for the java files inside my project.